# Apparent occurrence of the dual numbers in the Jordan decomposition

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Maybe this question is too elementary or too vague, but there might be something interesting here:

A $2 \times 2$ Jordan matrix is of the form $\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1  \\ 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix}$, which is the same as the matrix representation of the dual number $\lambda + 1\varepsilon \in \mathbb C[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)$. Other Jordan matrices are the sums of scalar matrices with nilpotent matrices of arbitrarily high order. I am wondering whether there's a tidy explanation for why something like the dual number algebra appears in the Jordan decomposition. I am wondering whether it has something to do with fancy things like non-reduced schemes.

Comment: Bigger Jordan blocks are the sum of a diagonal matrix and a nilpotent matrix of larger order than $2$. So they'll correspond not to dual numbers but to "numbers" in $\mathbb C[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^k)$ for integers $k$ larger than $2$.

Comment: An operator on a vector space (or a matrix, if you choose a basis) define on it a structure of a finite-dimensional module over $\mathbb{C}[x]$, i.e., an artinian sheaf on $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x]) \cong \mathbb{A}^1$. Such a sheaf is supported on a zero-dimensional subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^1$, and every such subscheme is a disjoint union of several copies of  $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^k)$.

Comment: There are some way to describe Hilbert scheme of C^2 using matrices, maybe such a description could be useful. (It's in Nakajima's book on Hilbert scheme)

Comment: @Sasha, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414908/apparent-occurrence-of-the-dual-numbers-in-the-jordan-decomposition#comment1063953_414908) seems like an answer to the question.  Would you post it?

Comment: @LSpice: OK, if you think this is appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

An operator on a vector space (or a matrix, if you choose a basis) defines on it a structure of a finite-dimensional module over $\mathbb{C}[x]$, i.e., an artinian sheaf on $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x]) = \mathbb{A}^1$. Such a sheaf is supported on a zero-dimensional subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^1$, and every such subscheme is a disjoint union of several copies of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^k)$.

Comment: What is this module?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: You say *An operator on a vector space (or a matrix, if you choose a basis) defines on it a structure of a finite-dimensional module over C[x],* What is this module explicitly?

Comment: A module is a vector space with some operators, right?

Comment: I know a module is. I want to understand this particular module which you've alluded to, but haven't defined anywhere.

Comment: I have defined a vector space and  an operator, hence I defined a module.

Comment: wait what. A module is an action of a ring on a set.

Comment: So, what do you need to define an action of $\mathbb{C}[x]$?

Comment: Yes. What actually is your module?

Comment: I don't think this is really an answer to my question.

Comment: It would be better if you think a bit before asking, but OK, here is a detailed (and tautological) explanation. Let $V$ be a vector space and let $A \colon V \to V$ be an operator. Consider the algebra homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[x] \to \mathrm{End}(V)$ that takes $x$ to $A$. It provides $V$ with a structure of a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module.